# Junction Table MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about a Junction table in  MySQL.

In my Junction Table, I store EmployerID, which references my Employer Table  and MeetingID, which references my Meetings Table.

Currently,  my Junction table looks like this:

```
+------------+------------+
| EmployerID |  MeetingID |
+------------+------------+
| Employer1  |  Meeting1  |
| Employer2  |  Meeting1  |
| Employer1  |  Meeting2  |
| Employer2  |  Meeting2  |
| Employer1  |  Meeting3  |
| Employer2  |  Meeting3  |
| Employer1  |  Meeting4  |
| Emokoyer2  |  Meeting4  |
+------------+------------+
```

However, based on my data I know that e.g. Employer1 attended only Meeting1 and Meeting4 and Employer2 attended only Meeting3 and Meeting4. However, because I have 4 meetings in total in my Meetings table, the junction table lists all EmployersID for all MeetingsID,

Is there a way to correct the Junction table, so that it will correctly display what meetings each employer attended?

Comment: The junction table shows whatever data was inserted into it.  If that data is wrong, then you should examine your business logic to find the root cause.  I don't view this a SQL problem per se.

Comment: Thank you for you answer Mr. Biegeleisen.

Comment: If you want to delete certain records from the junction table, and you have well-defined logic for that, then then us know and maybe someone can give you a query.

Comment: Have foreign key constraints. Only insert the rows needed. Consider having unique keys (composite keys) to eliminate the possibility of dupes if that is your situation (a person cannot attend the same meeting id more than once). Have a PK (often a composite key). Delete the residue to errantly  put in data via delete stmts against a PK